# How to determine the number of arguments passed to function?

Tags: python, parameters, signature, args

I have a function that takes a variable number of arguments. I would like (in the function) get the number passed. The declaration looks like this:

```py
def function(*args):
```

The function is called as follows:

```py
function(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Comment: Did you mean:`len(args)`?

Comment: I suppose If you do len(args), you will get the number of argument. Even If I does not understand what it means * .

Comment: @Gromph: It means the function accepts a variable number of arguments and they will be all put into list named `args`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the function as follows to get the values of the arguments:

```
def function(*args):
   for i in range(len(args)):
      print(args[i])

function(3, 5, 8)
```

Here is the result:

```
3
5
8
```

That is, `args[i]` receives the value of the i-th parameter passed to `function`.

Comment: It would be more Pythonic to iterate like this `for arg in args: print(arg)`

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of parameters passed, you can use the signature module.
Example:

```
from inspect import signature

def someMethod(self, arg1, kwarg1=None):
    pass

sig = (signature(someMethod))
print(len(list(sig.parameters)))
```

Output:

```
3
```

To get the names of the parameters, you do:

```
def someMethod(self, arg1, kwarg1=None):
    pass

sig = (signature(someMethod))
print(list(sig.parameters))
```

Read more
[here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)

Comment: That wouldn't work in my case, as the signature is *args, which doesnt represent the passed aguments